# Address showing blank in My Account section, One Step Checkout & Transactional Emails

Tags: email-templates, customer-account, transactional, address, onestepcheckout

I have a strange issue happening on our production environment. Where the address is printed out in the template files across the site it is blank. This is happening across the My Account section, One Step Checkout Saved Address and also the Transactional Emails.

We have a development server setup with the exact same code base which does not have the problem.

I have changed the theme to the default on production & also turned off all third party modules but that does not show the address either.

I'm presuming this must be server related or even in the database but I am running out of ideas to debug can anyone suggest anything?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I got a copy of the live database and put it on my local version and it seems thats where the problem lies as the address has now vanished again. 

The actual database records seem to be ok though as they are showing in the backend, its just the frontend, can't figure out what it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425713/create-account-last-name-required-even-when-value-given

Problem solved. There was an issue with the customer tables so I replaced those with the tables from our development server and that fixed the issue!

God bless Stack Overflow